# Something wrong with strcmp?

Tags: c, file, linked-list, strtok

My assignment is to read a file in to a linked list. The file contains a name and a letter indicating what to do with the name, either add or delete from list. The file is in this format:

Kathy a

Beverly a

Chuck a

Radell a

Gary a

Roger d

and so on...

The problem comes when i try to split up the name and the operation. The strcmp() doesn't even recognize the op_code variable in my code. I printed out both the name and the op_code and they print right unless i put a character near the op_code.

Here's my code:

```
//Tristan Shepherd

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char name[42];
    struct node *next;
};

void printList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *current = head;

    while (current)
    {
        printf("3 %s\n", current->name);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void addFront(struct node **head, char *newname)
{
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    strcpy(newnode->name, newname);

    newnode->next = (*head);

    (*head) = newnode;
}

void delete(struct node **head, char *namedelete)
{ 
    struct node* temp = *head, *prev;

    if (temp != NULL && temp->name == namedelete)
    {
        *head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    while (temp != NULL && temp->name != namedelete)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == NULL) return;

    prev->next = temp->next;

    free(temp);
}

void readfile(struct node *head)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("hw8.data", "r");

    char tname[42];
    char *tempname = (char*)malloc(42*sizeof(char));
    char *op_code = (char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));

    while(fgets(tname, sizeof(tname), file))
    {  
        tempname = strtok(tname, " ");
        op_code = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        printf("%s\n", tempname);
        printf("%s\n", op_code);

        if (!strcmp(op_code, "a"))
        {
            addFront(&head, tempname);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(op_code, "d"))
        {
            delete(&head, tempname);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printList(head);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    readfile(head);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I would put a space character in front of the `\n` in the second `strtok`. Sometimes there's extra whitespace at the end of the line. Also, you don't need the two `malloc`s. `strtok` returns a pointer into the `tname` array. And finally, I would add an `else {printf("bad opcode: '%s'\n", op_code); }` to the code

Comment: Tip: when printing troublesome text, precede and follow the text with sentinels.  Easier to detect unexpected white-space.  `printf("<%s>\n", tempname);`

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see with in `readFile()` is a memory leak.

```
char *tempname = (char*)malloc(42*sizeof(char));
char *op_code = (char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
```

should just be

```
char *tempname;
char *op_code;
```

`strtok()` breaks up the string in place, it does not produce a copy of the string, so no need to allocate extra memory.

I do see some issues in `delete()` however

You should be using `strcmp()` here instead of `==`, like you do in `readfile()`

```
if (temp != NULL && temp->name == namedelete)

while (temp != NULL && temp->name != namedelete)
```

You may also need to initialize `prev`.

With your code as-is, add seemed to be working fine, and with my changes, delete looks ok.